# How do I scale an image inside an iframe with css

Tags: css, iframe, google-sheets, embed, squarespace

**Use Case**

I have a survey I'm conducting with Google Forms. Survey results are aggregated in Google Sheets. I have a series of graphs that update dynamically as new results come in. I have a Squarespace website where I want to publish the charts. I can embed the charts with a code block where I copy and pasted the iframe embed code produced by Google Sheets.

**Problem**

As you probably know, iframes are not fully responsive. I've seen a number of articles with various techniques for making the iframe responsive. The example's I've learned from all use YouTube video players as the example for making them scaleable for a fully responsive website. I've followed the examples and near as I can tell I've got the iframe to respond to the size of the viewport, but not the image inside the iframe.

I've consulted two friends who run web dev shops, but I can't ask for too much help since I'd be asking them to work for free, and I don't ask my friends for free work.

**Link to JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/ArgyleAnalytics/z4rcv7hp/4/

Here is my HTML

```
<div class='embed-container'>
    <iframe src='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRPFtRq4MyzyU-MgDlL3duebxBNAHL6ySq2e_jatydzOseVyAzAHuoSA6VXAcalDkYMG1litTyKPkEn/pubchart?oid=501231490&format=image' scrolling="no" seamless frameboarder="0">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
<style>.embed-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    }

.embed-container iframe,
.embed-container object,
.embed-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    transform: scale(1.00);
    transform-orgin: ()
    }
</style>
```

**Notes on my Code**

I'm using an approach I've seen used in multiple blogs and the base code came from http://embedresponsively.com. One of my friends pointed me at this SO thread where I got the idea for the `transform: scale` you see in `.embed-container iframe`. `transform: scale` seems to get me part of the way there. When I adjust my code to `transform: scale(0.25)` it shrinks the graph which is what I want, but this is too inelegant an option for what I'm trying to achieve. Right now, my CSS uses an absolute value for the scale instead of using the edges of the iframe as a reference point (I think that's what I need to achieve).

**My Desired Outcome**

I would like the image inside the iframe to scale down relative to the edge of the iframe. Squarespace will automatically rearrange the placement of code blocks based on the viewport. If I can figure out a way to tie the `transform: scale` to the edges of the iframe I think that will give me what I need.

**Limitations**

I'd like to achieve this without any JS, but I'm flexible if that's what it takes since I can run `<scripts>` inside a Squarespace code block. If my PHP skills where strong enough I would probably just hand code my graphs with Google's Chart Visualization suite, but I don't have the time to study up to that level of proficiency.

I'm okay with hearing that what I want to do can't be done because of limitations within Google Sheets, but I don't know that I buy that. I can get the image to scale based on an absolute value, I'm hoping someone can find a way to help me scale my image inside the iframe based on the size of the iframe.

Comment: @pnuts Ya'll are volunteers offering to help strangers. The friends I mentioned are the ones for whom I might eventually wear out my welcome if I ask them for help too often.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its possible to effect the CSS of an iframed in page. You would have to add the responsive CSS to the page you're trying to embed. Since it is a google generated image that doesnt seem likely that you would have access to do that. What you could try and do is just download the image and place it on the square space site as an image and not an iframe.

Im not sure if the image's data is dynamic so that may effect what you can do. Have you thought of looking around for other graphing services? There might be something out there that will tie into google sheets or if you know javascript enough you can build your own graphs using googles api.

Comment: Sorry, But I think it is not possible because here issues of an image which is in an iframe so we can't style it if you able to give style then plz give inline style to an image like max-width:100%; height: auto; also in mobile view you need give min-height to iframe otherwise image looked in small device.

Comment: @tec4. Thanks for your reply. The data is very dynamic and I'm trying to create a webpage that will always pull in updated numbers when the page loads.

Comment: @KevinTaylor Yeah in that case you may have to dive into some Javascript or find a service that will tie into it google sheets and allow you to embed a dynamic graph form that service.